# How does a snack with a coffee slow down the caffeine's effect?

Tags: caffeine

I have stumbled upon the following sentence:

`Have your coffee with a snack to allow a slower release of caffeine into your system.`

Browsing the internet I could see exactly the same claims, not only in articles, but also in comments and unanswered questions.

There is however no reliable evidence or any kind of proof of it. I'm inclined to believe that it works, the question though is

**How exactly does a snack slow down the caffeine release?**

*Not sure if it's coffee-specific or a general biological way the things work, so I decided to ask here.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably due to the fact that your organism has nutriments from the snack to absorb at the same time , if everything mixs in your stomach then absorbtion will also be mixed . It's pretty much the same with alcohol.

Comment: Makes sense, especially since it is advised to get a fatty snack (which is harder for the organism to digest). However, it seems strange that such a tiny snack has such a huge impact on digestion.

Comment: You still have to digest it so it may only slow the absorbtion of the first half or even less of your coffee , but facts are here , it will have been slower ^^

Comment: How big of a factor is this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine says caffeine's biological half-life (the time required for the body to eliminate one-half of a dose) is 3–7 hours.